# NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I want to have a view in which I could add new contacts in the model "contacts" that I created.
Here are some lines of code that are concerned

views.py:

---

```
def contact(request):
form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    sujet = form.cleaned_data['sujet']
    message = form.cleaned_data['message']
    envoyeur = form.cleaned_data['envoyeur']
    renvoi = form.cleaned_data['renvoi']
    envoi = True
return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', locals())

def nouveau_contact(request):
sauvegarde = False
form = NouveauContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    contact = Contact()
    contact.nom = form.cleaned_data["nom"]
    contact.adresse = form.cleaned_data["adresse"]
    contact.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
    contact.save()
    sauvegarde = True
return render(request, 'blog/newcontact.html', {
    'form': form, 
    'sauvegarde': sauvegarde
})
```

---

forms.py:

---

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   sujet = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
   envoyeur = forms.EmailField(label="Votre adresse mail")


class NouveauContactForm(forms.Form):
   nom = forms.CharField()
   adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
   photo = forms.ImageField()

class Contact(models.Model):
   nom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   adresse = models.TextField()
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")

   def __str__(self):
      return self.nom
```

The error message tells me that "" NewContactForm "" is not defined
[this is the ERROR_MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEwgf.png)

Comment: you forgot the import

Comment: How do the different files relate? Which file gives the error message? What do the imports look like?

Comment: got it,, thanx a lot

Comment: If the question is answered, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the views at the top,

```
from .forms import NouveauContactForm
```

You forgot to import the form.

Comment: Could you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, then?